# Corn Tree Counting with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, counting

[image][image: How to count the corn trees?][image][image: Corn Tree]

How to count corn trees accurately with opencv based on the following image? I have tried HSV conversion with inRange but got nothing so far.

Is there a way for counting the trees correctly? Even with noise reduction I think that it won't count it property.

Comment: try some template matching...

Comment: Can you point me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is easier to solve when implementing few simple preprocessing steps. Look at the result I obtained:

[image]

Steps:

- Convert RGB to LAB image
- Extract A channel (discard L, B channels)
- Stretch/Maximize image contrast
- Use Otsu's optimal threshold selection for binarization
- Invert the image so that foreground is white, background is black

Based on this image template matching or other detection methods should work even better.

Comment: Alright, how about the smaller white points and the one at the right bottom corner? Shall I use a findContour for counting them?

Comment: The small point on the top left is actually a plant. To get rid of other smaller points you may use Erosion filter. I don't want to go into details of the second stage right now. That's up to you :-).

Comment: I'll post my code in a few minutes - I am a really newbie on this computer vision subject (just know the basics).

Comment: I have updated my post at the top with the source code. Otsu's Threshold and Erosion both are news to me :-)

Comment: `#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Mat src = imread("corn.jpg");
    if (src.empty()) {
        return -1;
    }

    Mat lab;

    cvtColor(src, lab, CV_BGR2Lab);
    imshow("LAB", lab);

    
    return 0;
}` **I am really stuck on that**

Comment: There is THRESH_OTSU, see http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#cv.Threshold

Comment: I got a src.type() == CV_8UC1 (assertion failed)

Comment: Mat otsu; threshold(lab, otsu, 10, 100, THRESH_OTSU);

Comment: Read what I have written and perform it in order. I will not debug your problem, you didn't even give me an upvote to my answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24229/discussion-between-marcelo-araujo-and-ypnos)

Comment: Here is another pointer: To extract the A channel before thresholding, use cv::split() function. Sorry, I have no time to go into chat.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4971714 - Not sure how to invert the colors according to your algorithm.

Comment: It seems you have a bug in the code as you do not split lab, but split src. For stretch contrast you can take minimum and maximum of image with cv::minMaxLoc() and then stretch the range to become [0;255]. You could also try cv::equalizeHist().
To invert the image, you just do A = 255 - A;

Comment: Hey, you are right - my fault just took a look about the splitting action, now it has been fixed. Thank you, I'll move forward (thanks again)

Comment: I got it, now I'll have to deal with the small noises (false positive corn trees).

Comment: please check the new image published above.

Comment: From now on, counting the corn trees in a proper way is just related with centroid analysis?

Comment: cv::Mat element = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE, cv::Size(21, 40));
cv::erode(otsu, otsu, element);

Answer (score 3):

I chose a template as follows...
[image: Template 1]
and when I tried to run a template match I got the following match..
[image]
The match was fine as because I chose the template from that part of the image.However the result image containing the values of the extent of match at different areas of the full image when threshold-ed looked like this..
[image]
So you can see that if you count the white patches (neglecting the small noises) you almost get the possible number of crops...!!

**EDIT**

More precise result you can get if you try the template matching in the **green plane of the RGB image**

Comment: How do I neglect the small noises (ignore smaller white points)?

Comment: 1) How to apply the extent of match at different areas of the full image?                                                               2) Did you use only one grayscale conversion?                          3) What sort of threshold did you do it?

Comment: findContours() in this case didn't solve the counting problem.

Comment: I have applied the template matching. However, I couldn't get a result such yours (black and white image with white patches).

Comment: Well, I would appreciate it :-)